How the correct way to implement a functionality
Guys, I have a doubt about the correct way to implement code with rails.
I have a functionality that saves some sales data from some operators who currently view them from spreadsheets.
(nsu, value, installments, date, flag, etc.)
I am implementing an integration with the API of some of these operators so that I can have this automatic function without having to upload some operators to Excel.
As I already have all the functionality working perfectly, I'm just going to fetch the data in a different way (for each operator) I thought about creating an empty model (without attributes) of some of these operators to place these functions within these models.
I do not know if i was clear.
but the idea would be to create a model for example for Stone where it would have the functions of get_token, get_sales, etc.. everything about that operator
I don't know if it's correct, and how would I generate this model? Could it generate normally?
rails g model Stone --skip-migration

it's called a "PORO" or "Plain Old Ruby Object". Feel free to create whatever Ruby objects you need. You are not constrained to the Rails standard MVC files. Since it's just another Ruby class, don't use the rails generator, just create a file. You can put them in the Rails concerns directories, if you are going to include them in your activerecord models. I put all these (many) classes in app/domain_models/, or if the functionality makes sense, put them in app/services.

Don't think of your code as which functions go where. Instead think of what responsibity (note that it's singular) each class has. Also don't get hung up on shoehorning all your code in models, views and controllers just because you're using a MVC framework. @LesNightingill's suggestion is a good starting point.

When integrating with an API  its usually good to have multple components with clearly defined responsibilities. Client classes should do HTTP and be the only class that that crosses the application boundry. Models can be used to represent the data in your application but should not touch the boundry or be coupled to the API in any other way. Mapping data between the API and your internal representation can be done in adapter classes.

You can just create a model file in models folder, just don't inherit it from ApplicationRecord:
# in app/models/my_custom_model.rb:
class MyCustomModel
  def my_method
    ...
  end
end


Rails also provides several helpers via Active Model which can be added to plain Ruby objects as needed.
